# reduce 5 volts to 3.3 volts with 1 ampere current

Tags: voltage-regulator

I need to convert 5v to 3.3v with a current requirement of 1 to 2 A. i reckon that i should use LDO and not buck converters. i need an elaborate and specific answer regarding the components which should be used and the circuit.

Comment: Why do you prefer a linear regulator? Efficiency will be only 66%, and the regulator will be producing up to 3.4 W of heat.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange.  What makes you think you want an LDO instead of a switching converter?  What trouble have you encountered in selecting a suitable solutions?

Comment: current seems small, so low dropout regulator seemed preferable over buck converter.

Comment: @TusharSingh 1 to 2A is quite a substantial amount of current by small electronic standards.  A switching regulator would be well worth it.  At 3.4W you'll need a decent little heatsink for the LDO as well.  It's probably better to go to a cheap switching regulator.

Comment: If this is powering the controller for a 50 kW induction furnace, maybe it's a "small" current. But in many digital design use cases, "small" currents would be measured in single-digit milliamps, and anything over a few 100 mA would be considered pretty large.

Comment: @Tushar: Welcome to EE.SE but "*i need an elaborate and specific answer ...*" is not how this site works as it is not a free design service where you can request that we generate 'elaborate' answers on demand. I suggest you research standard designs and post a schematic requesting assistance on whatever part you don't understand.

Answer (score 5):

Look up something called a *buck converter*.  These are DC to DC switching power supplies that have a lower output voltage than input voltage.  Such a buck converter will be smaller and probably cheaper than a linear regulator once you consider heat management.

*Think* about power dissipation and heat.  A linear regulator will drop (5 V)-(3.3 V) = 1.7 V.  That times 2 A is 3.4 W that it will dissipate.  Maybe the lost power is no concern in your design, but having to get rid of 3.4 W of heat can't be ignored.  You can't just use something in a TO-220 case sticking up into ambient air, for example.  This power level requires a large package, a heat sink, and/or possibly forced air cooling.